# netbeans enviromental variable

Tags: java, netbeans, environment-variables

What is the name of the enviromental variable that netbeans IDE uses ?

Comment: its because, if I develop a software using netbeans(and it runs perfectly), then take its java files and try to run the main class on cmd I get the error of class main not found , so i guess this has to do with the enviromental variables

Comment: `java` has an argument `-cp|-classpath`, you don't need envvars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because your class files are in a package.  Say you have your .java files in a src directory and your classes compile to a bin directory.  If your main class is in a package named `org.example` then you'd run your program from the command line as follows (make sure you're in the `bin` directory, not in `src`):

```
C:\MyProject\bin> java org.example.MyClass
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [these start up parameters](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqStartupParameters) with the NetBeans IDE